# Holomorphic extension on open disc

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f:\overline D\to\mathbb{C}$, where $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, is continuous on $\overline D$ and holomorphic on $D$ is it true that $f$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\overline D$?

Since $f$ is continuous on $\overline D$ then it has no poles, so it intuitively should extend to a holomorphic function on closed disc, but I don't know how to prove it.